# Does every Goldilocks planet in various solar systems inevitably have massive amounts of concentrated $\rm H_2O$ meteors?

Tags: forces, water, exoplanets, meteors, anthropic-principle

I’ve always been fascinated with the Anthropic Principle. Our universe seems to have our Chemical, biological, and physical properties/laws designed to favor the existence of life. Although the human race has never discovered life that has originated outside of planet Earth (at least to public knowledge), we’ve discovered many exoplanets we know contain large amounts of water.

With the unique characteristics of $\rm H_2O$ that separate it from all other compounds/molecules, like becoming less dense after freezing and being highly polarized, does every solar system with an Earth-like (able to contain liquid or solid water chemically or physically) planet within the Goldilocks zone inevitably have massive amounts of highly concentrated $\rm H_2O$ meteors?

Without many forces acting on particles in the emptiness of space or the out skirts of solar systems, chemical reactions or molecular dipole forces along with collisions would be the strongest acting forces. With $\rm H_2O$’s dipole moment exceeding all other compounds, over time higher concentrations of $\rm H_2O$ asteroid masses would form. And as those larger masses formed, they would eventually fall in contact with the gravity of a “pluto” or “Neptune,” to then be flung near a Goldilocks.

So, Does every Goldilocks planet in various solar systems inevitably have massive amounts of concentrated $\rm H_2O$ meteors?

Answer (score 1):

An interesting thought, but I don't think you can ascribe water asteroid formation, or any macro-scale formation, to molecular polarity.  While molecules of water are polar, a droplet of water is not polar, and a ball of ice is not polar.  The polarity only acts on the scale of nearby molecules.  Gravity and astronomical effects like solar wind will govern the formation of asteroids and planets.

What is true is that ice asteroid and comets can only form outside the Goldilocks zone, where solid water can exist, and then have to migrate inward.